# ¿Cómo puedo alinear a la izquierda este botón dentro de un div en un slider?

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy utilizando un slider de [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) con 3 slides, en el slider número 1 tengo un botón y en el tercer slide tengo el mismo botón pero con diferente destino al hacer click, el problema es que al trata de alinearlo en el slide 1 se pone en una posición y en el slide 3 se pone en otra, no logro hacer que se pongan en donde mismo a pesar de que son el mismo botón, ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
El css de mi div:

```
.banner-main {
    top: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    color: #FAFAFA;
    background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.6);
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    line-height: .3em;
    text-align: left;
}
```

El botón lo saque de [aquí.](https://codepen.io/sazzad/pen/yNNNJG) Es el cuarto botón de la sección "Victoria"

```
<div id="slide1">
        <div class="video-inline">
           <video  id="vid" class="video " loop="loop"  muted="muted" autoplay="autoplay">
              <source src="Videos/bannervideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
              <source src="Videos/bannervideo.webmhd.webm" type="video/webm" />
              <source src="Videos/bannervideo.oggtheora.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
              Tu navegador no soporta video HTML5.
           </video>
           <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
           <div class="video-timeline js-timeline">
              <div class="video-timeline-passed js-timeline-passed"></div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="banner-main">
           <h1 class="banner-header">PV MAN POWER</h1>
           <span>
              <h1 class="banner-sub-header">Mano de obra el&eacute;ctrica</h1>
           </span>
           <span>
              <h5 class="banner-desc">Expertos en obra fotovoltaica y obra el&eacute;ctrica con una gran trayectoria</h5>
           </span>
           <span>
             <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" style="margin-left: -6.4vW;"> <a href="#sectores-size" class="btn btn-sm animated-button victoria-four">Ver proyectos</a> </div>
           </span>
        </div>
     </div>
    <div id="slide3">
                <div class="banner-main">
                   <h1 class="banner-header">MARCA</h1>
                   <span>
                      <h1 class="banner-sub-header">Peritaje</h1>
                   </span>
                   <span>
                      <h5 class="banner-desc">Analis&iacute;s y revisi&oacute;n de sistemas fotovoltaicos</h5>
                   </span>
                   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"> <a href="#servicios-size" class="btn btn-sm animated-button victoria-four">Servicios</a></div>
                </div>
             </div>
```

Y este es el CSS de el botón que no consigo alinear.

```
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);

a.animated-button:link,
a.animated-button:visited {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    padding: 14px 15px;
    color: #fafafa;
    font-size: 55x;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    letter-spacing: .08em;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
a.animated-button:link:after,
a.animated-button:visited:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0%; /*Fonfo animado*/
    left: 50%; /*Fonfo animado*/
    top: 50%; /*Fonfo animado*/
    width: 150%;/*Fonfo animado*/
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.75s ease 0s;
}
a.animated-button:link:hover,
a.animated-button:visited:hover {
    color: #333333;
    text-shadow: none;
}
a.animated-button:link:hover:after,
a.animated-button:visited:hover:after {

}
a.animated-button:link,
a.animated-button:visited {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 6px;
    color: #FAFAFA;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
    overflow: hidden;
    letter-spacing: .08em;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    width: 180px;
}
a.animated-button.victoria-four {
    border: 1px solid #FAFAFA;
    left: 100px;
    margin: 0;
}
a.animated-button.victoria-four:after {
    background: #FAFAFA;
    opacity: .5;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotate(90deg);
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotate(90deg);
}
a.animated-button.victoria-four:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 600% !important;
}
```

Cualquier observación a parte de mi problema es aceptada, tengo poco en esto, gracias.

Comment: Buen día, Angel. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo funcional que podamos reproducir para ver el problema con facilidad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trate de simular tu codigo, y creo que encontre la solucion, 
El problema esta aqui, le estas asignando un left:100px;

Esto hace que tu boton salga 100px desplazado de la izquierda, alli el primer detalle.

```
 //Quitale ese left:100px;

a.animated-button.victoria-four {
    border: 1px solid #FAFAFA;
    left: 100px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

El siguiente boton tiene un style

```
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" style="margin-left: -6.4vW;"> <a href="#sectores-size" class="btn btn-sm animated-button victoria-four">Ver proyectos</a> </div>
```

Quitale ese estilo y con eso deberia de funcionar.

PD: No subo el ejemplo funcional porque no pude hacer que funcionara en el snipet